# Can't get url request to show, 404

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm completely new to backend, working through the djangobook tutorial. If I'm missing any vital information, let me know. The first task is to get 'Hello World' to show up on your development server, and it keeps returning 404. The two files in question being the views.py (my hello world file) and urls.py

this is the views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

this is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from mysite.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
]
```

I feel like its not finding the views file correctly? This is how there set up, exactly as he said to do it in the tutorial

Comment: *What* keeps returning 404? What url are you going to?

Comment: Are you going to `/hello` or to `/hello/`? - it can be important depending on whether the `APPEND_SLASH` settings is on - it [should be on by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash) but if you're working through another resource, it may have done something different. Can you post your settings.py file (minus the secret key)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL's in two places. One in your app like you did, and the other in the django directory. [This link](http://dfpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter_01.html#writing-the-code) has more information on how to do it.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    url(r'', include('hello.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It was at http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/, also used HunkDivine's answer as another option